# Авторизация oauth 2.0

Tags: vkontakte-api

Хочу сделать `войти через вконтакте` (Авторизация `oauth 2.0`). Все вроде понял кроме одного: После чего как пользователь полностью авторизовался вконтакте отправляет ответ в формате `json`:

```
{
    "access_token":"533bacf01e11f55b536a565b57531ac114461ae8736d6506a3",
    "expires_in":43200, 
    "user_id":6492
}
```

И что получается `user_id` у себя в БД  будем хранить?, как то не могу понять, или как дальше действовать?, что нужно сохранить у себя в БД, чтобы сессия начилось?

Comment: Читали [документацию](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)? - что именно после этого не понятно?

Comment: Документация прочитал, Мне не понятно как начать сессию?

Comment: @bemulima, у вас есть ``user_id``, у вас есть ``platform = vk``. Просто начните сессию. Как это сделать уже слегка зависит от языка программирования, который вы не указали.

Comment: писать программу буду на пхп, просто не могу представить как это все будет делаться. Получается мне нужно после авторизации сохранить имя пользователя у себя в БД, чтоб проверить есть ли такой пользователь в БД если нет то регистрация с помощью ВК - так действовать?

Comment: Чё, никто из ХэшКодевцев еще не подключил авторизация oauth 2.0? Мне бы алгоритм дальнейшей движении:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Алгоритм ничем не отличается от того, что вам пришлось бы делать, если бы пользователь был зарегистрирован на вашем сайте.

Если входить можно через несколько соц.сетей, то лучше для пользователя хранить его user_id **в сети** и `id` самой сети в отдельной таблице по **своему** `user_id`.

Алгоритм:

1. при успешном входе нового пользователя
2. нет такого `user_id` в БД - создаете новую запись в БД
3. [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) и сохранение авторизации

Answer (score 4):

Здесь все подробно написано: [Авторизация через ВКонтакте, Mail.ru и другие для самых начинающих](http://habrahabr.ru/post/126717/) .